# Создание прогресса загрузки в консоли linux

Tags: c++, linux

Если набрать в консоли команду, например

```
sudo apt-get install code
```

То в консоли будет строчка **Чтение списков пакетов… %x**, где **%x** это прогресс того самого чтения. То есть, происходит обновление конкретной цифры.
Как это сделать на C++? То есть, выводить значение прогресса, изменяя только цифру. Обычный *std::cout* просто пишет дальше в потоке.

Comment: [Управляющие последовательности ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в данном конкретном случае можно и без ANSI, просто `\r` или `\b`